# How to optimize a lot of switch cases?

Tags: java, switch-statement

How could I optimize having a lot of switch cases? Is there some other method to do what I'm attempting to do?

I have a time slider and this slider updates a variable `currentTime` with the value (1-24) where the current slider is and calls the `updateTime()` method. In this method I have switch cases for 1 - 24 (only 3 in this example). Instead of making 24 switch cases, could I do this in a much simpler way?

```
private void updateTime() {
    switch (currentTime) {
        case 1:
            hourlyData = weatherAPI.HourlyReport(1);
            setHourlyData();
            break;
        case 2:
            hourlyData = weatherAPI.HourlyReport(2);
            setHourlyData();
            break;
        ...
        case 24:
            hourlyData = weatherAPI.HourlyReport(24);
            setHourlyData();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Oops");
            break;
    }
}
```

--

```
public Map HourlyReport(int hour) {
    Hourly hourly = new Hourly(fio);
    //In case there is no hourly data available
    if (hourly.hours() < 0) {
        System.out.println("No hourly data.");
    } else {
        hourlyData.put("Temp", hourly.getHour(hour).temperature()); // Temperature
        hourlyData.put("TempFeel", hourly.getHour(hour).apparentTemperature()); // Feel Temperature
        hourlyData.put("Humidity", hourly.getHour(hour).humidity()); // Humidity
        hourlyData.put("WindSpeed", hourly.getHour(hour).windSpeed()); // Wind Speed
        hourlyData.put("Precip", hourly.getHour(hour).precipProbability()); // Precipitation
        hourlyData.put("TimeStamp", hourly.getHour(hour).time());// TimeStamp
    }
    return hourlyData;
}
```

Comment: Hum, what about `if (currentTime < 1 || currentTime > 24) { Oops } else { hourlyData = weatherAPI.HourlyReport(currentTime); }`?

Comment: unable to understand what your problem is, the above code is the real correct way of doing what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of a switch is not justified in this case. Use a simple `if`

```
if (currentTime > 0 && currentTime < 25) {
    hourlyData = weatherAPI.HourlyReport(currentTime);
    setHourlyData();
} else {
    System.out.println("Oops");
}
```

Comment: Completely right, unsure why I went with a switch case! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would validate first

```
private void updateTime() {
    if (currentTime < 1 || currentTime > 24) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("currentTime: " + currentTime);

    hourlyData = weatherAPI.HourlyReport(currentTime);
    setHourlyData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple `if` statement to validate `currentTime`'s value and just pass it to `weatherAPI.HourlyReport`:

```
private void updateTime() {
    if (currentTime >= 1 || currentTime <= 24) {
        hourlyData = weatherAPI.HourlyReport(currentTime);
        setHourlyData();
    } else{
        System.out.println("Oops");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private boolean isValidHour(){
        if (currentTime >= 1 && currentTime <= 24) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    private void updateTime() {
          if(this.isValidHour())
            hourlyData = weatherAPI.HourlyReport(currentTime);
          else
            System.out.println("Oops");
}
```